# "View all settings pages" on the profile settings page for a narrow screen

Tags: support, profile-page

What does it mean in the [profile settings page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current)?

> [image: View all setting pages]

Tapping on this block does nothing.

Comment: I think my profile doesn't have this link? It's probably only shown if a narrow screen is detected.

Comment: @bad_coder you can just reduce window’s width even on desktop to reproduce this issue.

Comment: It's not a link; it's a description for the drop-down. Perhaps because the "Navigation" label isn't descriptive enough. I think using a different label and getting rid of the secondary description would be better.

Comment: To supplement 41686d6564's comment, the "View all settings pages" and "Navigation" labels are both wrapped in a single `<label>` HTML element which is pointing to the `<select>` dropdown. If you click (or tap) on "Navigation" or "View all settings pages" you will notice that the dropdown gets a blue glow around it as in your screenshot. So it is actually doing something: it puts focus on the dropdown. Perhaps in some browser it also expands the dropdown, in which case the "View all settings pages" text would make sense.