# UpDown buttons cover the text in answer ordering combobox

Tags: bug, design, mobile-chrome, answer-order, touch-screen

On mobile devices (e.g. iPad) UpDown buttons cover the text in answer ordering combobox:

> [image]

It seems that such buttons could be painlessly removed at all on touchscreen devices.

Comment: I don't know about Apple devices, but maybe you have a custom font size setting? On my Android device the text of the dropdown is smaller than regular text, which means both the text and the arrows fit easily within the width of the list. Note also that this is not a combobox (i.e., a combination between a free text input and a list) but a dropdown list. The two arrows help the user identify that this is the case, i.e., that they can't type anything but have to choose from predefined options. See also https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/131775 for example.

Comment: @Marijn I'm not a web developer, so for me it looks as a [ComboBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). There's other [related thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371564/339911) about UX on that type of input elements.

Comment: Under [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks) on the .NET site that you linked it is noted that "A ComboBox displays a text box combined with a ListBox, which enables the user to select items from the list or enter a new value". Using that terminology, the element here on SE is a ListBox only, i.e., entering a new/custom value is not possible.

Comment: About the link to the settings page in the profile: that is indeed also a ListBox/dropdown, and it has arrows. I'm not sure why you linked to that example? In any case, the question I linked was specifically about the issue of "should this element have arrows on mobile" and the answer was yes, because it makes the input instantly recognizable as a dropdown list. Maybe that question and answer is not the most authoritative source but I thought it gave a clear answer and other more extensive sources about UI/UX affordances of (input) elements say more or less the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue looks fixed now:

> [image: Answer sort order]

Tested on the same iPad Pro 11" iPadOS 16.3.1
Chrome 110.0.5481.114